# How to set the image as a background using Url to Image formatter?

Tags: 8, theming, entities, media

We have a need to set an element such as `<div>` to have an image as a background. I am trying to figure out the way to get the image to display as a background but also with the image style that was used.

The image field (field_image) in question is used in multiple view modes with different image styles.

Example:

1. Basic page view mode: default, field_image with format = image and image style = large
2. Basic page view mode: promoted, field_image with format = image and image style = small
3. Basic page view mode: small tile, field_image with format=image and image style = medium

How can I accomplish the code below? Would the proposed solution work as I am not sure it is safe to use `['#markup']`?

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper__image" style="background-image: url('{{ file_url(node.field_image.entity.uri.value) }}')"></div>
  <div class="wrapper__content">
    <!-- some text here -->
</div>
```

Currently on View mode:

1. Field_image with Format = Image, Image Style = large

Current problem:

1. `node.field_image.entity.uri.value` returns the original images, not the one where the image style is applied.

Proposed solution:

1. set format = URL to image
2. image style = large
3. update the twig template to use `node.field_image.0['#markup]`

Comment: @Hudri the problem i have with that question and answer is that it doesn't address the original question. In that question and mine, we need a way to pull the image style in the preprocess hook. The best answer simply puts "myimagestyle" and assumes that the field will always have that image style. That is not the case in my question. I will update it to reflect it

Comment: What doesn't work with `style="background-image: url('{{ content.field_image }}');` in your template?

Comment: Ah, I guess your issue are the wrapping `<div>` of the field formatter. You usually can access the raw value of any field by adding the delta to it, e.g. `{{ content.field_image.0 }}`

Comment: @Hudri using the raw value returns the original url for the image. When an image style is applied to an image an image is created that is something along the lines of `sites/default/files/styles/large/image-url.png`. I want to get that URL

Comment: Use must use the raw (calculated) value of the `content` render array, not the value from the `node` entity.